# The cell doesnt show a complete image

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I want to do a Cell with a yellow background and one orange box with a text and after an image with a medium size, but it doesn't work. The image doesn't appear big and I can't use a margin

This is my XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.PromocoesView"
         BackgroundImage="promocoesbackground"
         Title="Promoções">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="listview_promocoes" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0 ">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>

                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding titulo}" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"/>

                        <Image Source="{Binding imagem}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    </StackLayout>


                </ViewCell>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

This is the bad result (with 2 item - u can't see the image)

[image]

I want to do something like this but I can't use margin because when I use it, the app doesn't work.

[image]

It needs to be one item of a ListView.
All items should be like this.

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that Layout in your ListView item with something like this:

```
<ListView
        RowHeight="170" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <!-- Outter box containing two boxes -->
            <StackLayout 
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <!-- First box with Title, Image and Text -->
                <StackLayout 
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            Padding="10, 5" 
                            BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                    <Label 
                            Text="YOUR_TITLE"
                            BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
                    <Image 
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            BackgroundColor="Fuchsia" 
                            HeightRequest="60" />
                    <Label 
                            Text="YOUR_OTHER_TEXT"
                            BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <!-- Second box with Text -->
                <StackLayout 
                            VerticalOptions="End" 
                            Margin="0, 8, 0, 0" 
                            Padding="10, 5" 
                            BackgroundColor="Lime">
                    <Label 
                            Text="YOUR_TEXT_OTHER_BOX"
                            BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I guess you might need to do a few little changes to get it exactly as you want it but this is pretty close.

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps.-

Comment: I used it but my image isnt big again.. like the photo I posted here. u can 
see only a little part of the picture in my app :/
I dont know what is happend...

Comment: it seems a line...in my app it seems A line :/